# How to cache a custom API call?

Tags: shortcode, rest-api, cache, performance, plugin-wp-supercache

I build a little Python API and would like to cache the responses for 24-hrs.

As I use it in a shortcode like `[google keyword="example"]` it will always do the API-call once I open the specific Wordpress site.

I use the shortcode more than once, so the pagespeed is kinda slow. **There is also a problem with too many requests on the API which I want to prevent by the caching** Or is there another workaround?

Is there an easy way to cache my `PHP-curl`?

The code is basically only a curl post-request to my Python API.

I am also open for Plugins like fastest-cache, I just need an easy solution. My PHP knowledge is not really good.

Thank you for your ideas and help!

**EDIT // little snipped of what the function does**

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => '***',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{"keyword" : "'. $atts['keyword'] .'" }',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
$data = json_decode($response);

curl_close($curl);
return $data->result; 
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use transients: https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/transients/ I can't add anything that's not in that documentation without an example of what you're currently doing.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I added the function. Thanks for you help!